# Add new input and use this without modify HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have only:

```
<div>
    <textarea id="names"></textarea>
</div>
```

I can't modify html. I can use only jQuery. Is possible make something like:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="yes">
<div style="display:none">
   <textarea id="names"></textarea>
</div>

$("#yes").click(function(){
    $("#names").parent().show();
})
```

Default if page is loaded and ready should be only:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="yes">
```

If i checked this then show me div with textarea.

Is possible make without modify HTML? If yes, how?

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/2ZMQz/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var checkbox = $('<input type="checkbox">');
var parent   = $('#names').parent().hide().before(checkbox);

checkbox.click(function() {
    parent.toggle();
});
```

​

http://jsfiddle.net/2ZMQz/14/

Comment: You're missing the id in the checkbox

Comment: Thanks, but it's not necessary for this example.

Comment: You could do `var checkbox = $('<div>TEST TEST</div><input type="checkbox">');`

Comment: note that this would add a clickhandler to the text, too. You should create another Object for that.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
$("#names").parent().hide().before('<input type="checkbox" id="yes" />');
```

You can improve the checkbox functionality by using toggle instead of show

```
$("#yes").click(function(){
    $("#names").parent().toggle();
})
```

As the name suggests it will toggle the visibility, so if you deselect the checkbox it hides the content.

http://jsfiddle.net/2ZMQz/7/

Comment: When `#yes` is checked, your textarea is hidden

Comment: +1. Beat me to it with same code, may as well have my fiddle [edited].

Comment: @DirkShags Your own text works for me, what's the issue you're experiencing?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this.

```
$("#names").parent().hide().before('<input type="checkbox" id="yes">');

$("#yes").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $("#names").parent().show();
    } else {
        $("#names").parent().hide();    
    }});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2ZMQz/15/